# Safely use ASP.NET Core's UserManager and IdentityDbContext simultaneously

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, dbcontext, asp.net-core-identity

Whenever I do anything related to auth, I use `UserManager` rather than `IdentityDbContext`. I always avoided using both simultaneously as I'm unsure how they interact.

Now I find myself in a situation that I need to query the database, so must use the context.

I register my context as per request, I think `UserManager` is also registered that way when calling `services.AddIdentityCore()` in startup.

What I'm worried about: if I perform work in one then is it safe to use from the other, will there be implicit race conditions based on which calls "save" first, do they share a change tracker, etc.?

*Is it "safe" to use both at the same time?*

Comment: UserManager do query on db

Comment: *I'm unsure how UserManager is registered* -- i think you can get some clue from [src](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/Core/src/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs) `services.TryAddScoped<UserManager<TUser>>();`

Comment: no you can't do it ..just the query it wrap in form of find by name etc .. but you can safely do your query with dbcontext on user table etc

Comment: No user manager [doesn't expose the store](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/3f41ac1ea4b2932167f0a968cc562453a060c45c/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserManager.cs#L136).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use both in an override of UserClaimsPrincipalFactory, without problems. I call UserManager.UpdateAsync() to save updates to the user, and use the injected context to retrieve additional data related to user authorizations.

Comment: Thanks. So changes you make in one are visible in the other?

Comment: The changes are all saved to the database, so they are visible at the next data retrieval. I don't know if the in-use context is shared with the UserManager, but you could do a test to find out, if that's necessary in your scenario.